# Fire event on value change of double

Tags: c#, wpf, events, inotifypropertychanged

I've used `INotifyPropertyChanged` within a custom class to fire an event when a variable has changed, but I was wondering if there was a simple way to fire an event on a single variable's change, such as a double.

For instance, in a WPF app, if I have

```
private double a;
```

in `MainWindow.xaml.cs`, is there a **simple** way to fire the event any time `a` is assigned to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to create a Setter for a, which then fires the properychange event/custom event instead of encapsulate `a` into a class.

Something like this:

```
private double a;

    public double A
    {
        get { return a; }
        set { a = value;
              firepropertyChange(a);
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

A field doesn't have any means of tracking changes.  In order to make it work, it would need to be a property, and something would need to handle the tracking. That is the purpose of the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

The normal means of tracking changes to this value would be to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your class.

Answer (score 0):

*Yes* (depends), if you wrap your variable access through a property and fire your event on change, and make sure all access to that variable is through the property, like

```
private double a;

public double PropertyA
{
    get
    {
        return a;
    }
    set
    {
        // set value and fire event only when value is changed
        // if we want to know when value set is the same then remove if condition
        if (a != value)
        {
            a = value;
            PropertyChanged("PropertyA");
        }
    }
}

// when changing a, make sure to use the property instead...
PropertyA = 5.2;
```

...otherwise, no

Comment: providing a string parameter is kind of bad style and non-generic. You should provide `A` itself

Comment: @StefanoL you are partially correct, though it's not bad in this case.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms133020.aspx, also, it's a hardcoded value, problem arises with user input

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C# 5.0, you can employ `CallerMemberName` attribute this way:

```
class MyData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string _anotherProperty;
    public string AnotherProperty
    {
        get { return _anotherProperty; }
        set
        {
            _anotherProperty = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string caller = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(caller));
        }
    }
}
```

As you see you just have to call `RaisePropertyChanged();` in `set` for each property, without typing the property names over and over.

Another approach would be to define a `ModelBase` class:

```
class ModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (!Object.Equals(field, value))
        {
            field = value;

            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

And then derive your model from `ModelBase`:

```
class Conf : ModelBase
{
    NodeType _nodeType = NodeType.Type1;

    public NodeType NodeType
    {
        get { return _nodeType; }
        set { Set(ref _nodeType, value); }
    }
}
```